# adding Virtual PC 2007 to host network

Tags: networking, virtual-pc

I am using Virtual PC 2007 with Windows xp Pro as the Guest. 
Is it possible to add the Virtual PC to the network of the guest PC and to the domain of the Guest PC?
I enabled NAT shared networking but that only allows internet access on the guest..
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This shouldn't be a problem when you add the guest to host's physical adapter:

In the settings for your VM, go to Networking and instead of "Shared networking (NAT)", select the NIC that's connected to the network on your host (e.g. "Realtek RTL8116 Gigabit Ethernet", or whatever your NIC is; this is equivalent to VMWare's Bridged Mode). That way, the guest will appear as a real computer on your network, and will work like a physical box on the network.

IIRC, MS VPC bypasses the default Windows firewall on the host, so only the guest's firewall applies; for other FW products, you may need to enable something like "permit packets not destined for this host".

Comment: In settings-Networking, I can see only three options in the drop-down lists of options provided.
-Not Connected
-Local only
-NAT
The VirtualPC help file (.chm) also discusses such as option as mentioned by you,it is given in the help file under the heading -
"Managing network adapter availability for virtual machines"
but the "NIC-of-the-host" option isnt available somehow.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the above answer-

**1.**

> Inside the Local Area Connection
>   Properties- VM Network Services Driver
>   wasnt installed without which the NIC
>   option wont appear in the Virtual
>   machine Network Adapter Configuration.
>
> I reinstalled the Virtual PC and that
>   entry **Virtual Machine Network
>   Driver** appeared.

**2.**

> Another helpful resource-

http://blogs.msdn.com/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2007/01/15/fixing-broken-virtual-networking.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be a problem as long as you can connect to a domain controller from the virtual computer.

If you know the IP address of a domain controller, try to ping it. Then try to ping it using the computer name, to see if name resolution is working correctly. What happens when you join a domain using Control Panel | System. Do you receive an error message?

I have not used Virtual PC, only VMWare workstation on Linux, so I do not know how the networking setup is on Virtual PC. On VMWare, you can choose between bridged and NAT networking for a virtual machine. I have been able to set up Windows guest computers as members of a windows domain using both kinds of network setup.

Comment: trying to joing domain using My Computer - Computer Name - Change Name gives. Access is Denied. 
This is the same process I followed to join my xp host to Domain but unable to join windows server 2003 guest (virtual pc2007).

Comment: Are you logged in as a user with administrative rights on the guest computer?